# stop loading website with a message due to incompatablity

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have developed a simple website using HTML5 and CSS3. I had lots of difficulties making it compatible with browsers other than chrome. "Changing the background image" Animation did not work in Firefox, IE. It worked only in Chrome. I want that visitors of my website should be able access website only if they have chrome, else it should give a warning message, or it may then open the chrome download page. I just don't want visitors to be able to view the "not so pleasant" website that is actually very bad in all other browsers but not chrome.
JavaScript would be good but I don't know anything about it. You can check the website here: http://aspspider.org/samarth

Comment: Better to develop for the browser that has the most issues (usually IE) and then tweak for more compliant browsers. It ends up being less work in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the CSS properties that I have used are not supported in any other browser, so now I  just need to prevent users from being able to view site if they don't have google chrome.

Comment: Don't forget that chrome is only around 40% of the browser market currently so restricting people to just use chrome would be cutting out a large chunk of potential visitors.

Comment: I know, I just want to learn this...

Comment: I think this question did not deserve a downvote. Although it is not a good practise only to show a website in one browser, the question itself is clear and the reasons for this approach are pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try google frame. It could load as soon as client is IE browser:

http://www.google.com/chromeframe?prefersystemlevel=true

Alternatively detect if browser is Chrome using JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
if (!is_chrome) window.location.href = "/get-chrome"; // or something...
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think it is an optimal solution. All my visitors will not have Google Frame installed. I need a script like think to detect the client's browser and load the website only if the browser is Chrome.

Comment: Please tell me where to put this code, how to use this?. I don't know anything about JavaScript.

Comment: try putting it between <head></head> tags

Comment: You say they all wont have Google Frame installed bu are coding to expect them all to have Google Chrome installed?

Comment: Google Frame needs to installed as a plugin, How would I make sure that all my visitors have it installed! If they have chrome, the site loads, else it doesn't... simple.

Comment: sorry, try the altered code above, it should say if (!is_chrome) window.location.href = "/get-chrome"; // or something...

Answer (score 1):

Websites are normally developed to be compatible with most users, not few. I strongly recommend that you redesign your webpage, or at least build a better looking one that doesn't have quite the functionality as Chrome's version, but is still useable by people with IE and FF. Limiting your webpage to people with Chrome is a very bad idea. If you really want chrome users to be able to get the full functionality that you have, then create a separate website in the background that is built for all other browsers. Then, when a user not using chrome loads the Chrome page (by default), then redirect them to the secondary, less functional webpage, and put a notification at the top of the secondary page with something along the lines of`"You are not using Google Chrome. To fully utilize this webpage, please *Download google Chrome* (That's a link to GC's download page) and *reload* (link to the default start page) this webpage in that browser instead." The redirect script would be as Merca suggested above:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
if (!is_chrome) window.location.href = "nonchrome/IEindex.html"; // redirects to IE & FF compatible webpage
</script>
```

Comment: thank you. I can make it look equally beautiful in FF, with one exception. I have create CSS animations with keyframes. I changed the background image of a DIV in these keyframes. The -webkit syntaxes work fine for chrome but I cant find anything working for FF. If you can help, please tell me the corresponding syntaxes for FF.

Comment: Normally, I have found that to do FF syntaxes, you just change `-webkit` to `-moz`. so for example, there is a `-webkit-border-radius` for webkit browsers, as well as a `-moz-border-radius` for FF (although browsers are beginning to transition over to just `border-radius` now...) I'm not sure if this syntax fix applies to what you are doing or not, but it's a start.

Comment: Thanks @bspymster . I tried both  the syntaxes but nothing seems to be working with FF. I need it for background image like,

@-moz-keyframes title_toggle {
from { background-image:url(images/title.png); }
75%{ background-image:url(images/title_hover.png); }
to { background-image:url(images/title.png); }
}

But this is not working. I tried -moz-background-image also. No luck!

Comment: Well it looks like you got a solution above, so if you are still having issues, post it in a new comment, but all browsers support the `background-image` property, so no need to tack on the `-moz` before it.

Comment: Yes, it should work but it is not!

@keyframes is not working either.